# How to share / deduplicate .bazelrc across multiple git repositories?

Tags: git, bazel

I have a collection of git repositories, each of which is a Bazel project with a `.bazelrc` file. These `.bazelrc` files end up containing a lot of repetition across these repositories. I'd like to eliminate the duplication by lifting the common parts of the various `.bazelrc` files into a shared `.bazelrc`.

Is there a good way to do this besides obvious things like a) use a mono-repo, b) use a git submodule for the `.bazelrc` file or some equivalent setup script to pull the shared `.bazelrc`? As far as I understand, the normal Bazel mechanisms for pulling in an external dependency (`{git,http}_archive`) would not work because Bazel will attempt to read `.bazelrc` before parsing `WORKSPACE`.

Comment: There may be a lot of repetition, but I would categorize that as incidental repetition. There's a tradeoff between duplicating configuration across independent repositories and creating a new external dependency for each of those projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global .bazelrc file in /etc/bazel.bazelrc
Bazel looks in few locations when configuring itself. https://bazel.build/run/bazelrc#bazelrc-file-locations

Comment: If somebody `git clone`'s one of these repos, I'd like to avoid them needing to modify their global bazel configuration as this could disrupt other bazel projects on that system. Even if this was fine, there would need to be a separate repository housing this bazelrc that would need to be copied/merged with their `/etc/bazel.bazelrc` -- ideally this would be seamless to users of the repository.